# The edge is sticking out in Object mode

Tags: edges

[image]

Guys, Idk what I did wrong, but here I have an edge sticking out while I'm in Object mode and I have no idea how to fix that Can someone help pls. Y'all sure can ask for more details

[image]

Comment: Hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/ probably a floating edge?

Comment: I will. We would like to help, but at the moment there really isn't much to help off of. Can you give us more details please?

Comment: As others have said, please share your file. but is this down the centre of the mirror? If so, do you have an internal face behind it? If you do, try deleting it.

Comment: @moonboots blend exchange doesn't work for me so I uploaded it on my drive: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jiZ35__F6AV8WMZrm9h2-thLS1rFniII/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter I think there's smth with that edge because in object mode and in edit mode it stands out (In edit mode it's darker than all other edges) I tried deleting it and even deleting faces but it became worse, so here's where I am. You can look up the blender itself here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jiZ35__F6AV8WMZrm9h2-thLS1rFniII/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @JohnEason I tried deleting its faces and faces around it but nothing worked out. here I uploaded it: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jiZ35__F6AV8WMZrm9h2-thLS1rFniII/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @BDYGE I've just added the file link into your question. - No problem uploading it here. Anyhow you now have your answer from moonboots.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an edge overlapping a face (see the image, I've selected the face), remove the edge with <kbd>X</kbd>> *Delete Edge* and join the vertices in order to cut the face:

[image]